# Adding a Menu Page to The Dashboard

Tags: page-template, dashboard

http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php?page=allValue.php

I would like to know the location of `allValue.php` file.

Comment: In a plugin, probably. Or it might just be a slug registered in [add_menu_page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/) that looks like a PHP filename. You'll have to look at your plugins - it's not from core.

Comment: @Rup Thanks. I am developing a plugin. I would like to know the location. Where should I place the file ?Thanks.

Comment: @abuabu It sounds like you're trying to create an admin page in the WordPress dashboard. Is that right? If so, can you provide a bit more context as to what you're trying to accomplish? Here's the codex for creating admin pages: https://codex.wordpress.org/Adding_Administration_Menus

Comment: @abuabu are you asking where an existing admin page is located? Or are you asking how to add an admin page to WP Admin? `allValue.php` doesn't mean there's a file named `allValue.php`, it's just a coincidence, it's just an identifier, not a filename, e.g. `/wp-admin/admin.php?page=jetpack` is valid

Comment: Thanks @TomJNowell for your reply. I am asking how to add an admin page to WP Admin. I am trying to develop a Plugin. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @MikeNGarrett. Yes, I am trying to create an admin page in the WordPress dashboard. I am trying to develop a Plugin. Where should I place the page ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to know the location of allValue.php file.

**That's not how it works.** The value of `page` doesn't tell WP which file to load, it's just a name, an identifier ( the `menu_slug` to be specific ).

For example, we can use this code to add a top level menu page to WP Admin:

```
/**
 * Register a custom menu page.
 */
function registerAbusAdminMenu() {
    add_menu_page(
        'Abus Menu',
        'Abus menu',
        'manage_options',
        'abu',
        'helloAbu'
    );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'registerAbusAdminMenu' );

function helloAbu() {
    echo "<p>Hello Abu!</p>";
}
```

Notice that the menu slug parameter I chose was `abu`. Some people don't like picking a menu slug though, they use the name of the file the code is in, but that's just coincidence. WP doesn't use that value to load a file ( that would be a security vulnerability ), it's the 5th argument to the function that controls what gets displayed/loaded, not a filename.

[See the docs here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Adding_Administration_Menus) for other functions to add submenus, options pages, etc, each function will have explanations and examples

Comment: I was just putting a similar answer together. Mine also started with "That's not how it works." 

Comment: @MikeNGarrett feel free to post your own answer, different perspectives on the solution can help understanding, and you might write a better answer :p

Comment: Nope! Yours looks great.

Comment: Thanks @TomJNowell for your amazing explanation. You are really a BOSS. Thanks